# vue escaping object child as parameter

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, parameters

I want to build a helper function to reduce my redundant code lines.
Instead of doing nearly the same over and over i want to use that function to simple add a parameter and reduce the lines of code.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- TODO: ADD ALL PROPS NOW! -->
    <UserInfo
      :user-name="userData.userName"
      :budget="userData.budget"
      :leftover="userData.leftover"
    />
    <UserIncExp />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserInfo from '../User/UserInfo.vue';
import UserIncExp from '../User/UserIncExp/_UserIncExp.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    UserInfo,
    UserIncExp
  },
  data() {
    return {
      test: '',
      userData: {
        userName: '',
        budget: '',
        leftover: '',
        inc: [],
        exp: [],
        active: false
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  watch: {
    '$route.params.userId': {
      handler() {
        this.loadUserDataFromState();
      }
    },
    immediate: true
  },
  created() {
    this.loadUserDataFromState();
  },
  methods: {
    loadUserDataFromState() {

      // this.userData.userName = this.$store.state.users[this.$attrs.userId].userName;
      // this.userData.budget = this.$store.state.users[this.$attrs.userId].salery;
      // this.userData.leftover = this.$store.state.users[this.$attrs.userId].leftover;

      this.helper(userName);
    },
    // CHECK HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    helper(data) {
      return this.userData.data = this.$store.state.users[this.$attrs.userId].data;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

but i dont get why i am not able to use `data` as an parameter to use it then in the executed function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) like so:

```
loadUserDataFromState() {
  this.helper("userName");
},
helper(key) {
  this.userData[key] = this.$store.state.users[this.$attrs.userId][key];
}
```

`helper` expects a key (which is a string).

**Note:** `helper` doesn't need to return anything.

---

An alternative way which doesn't require the function `helper` at all is to use a loop over an array of keys like so:

```
loadUserDataFromState() {
  for(let key of ["userName", "salery", "leftover"]) {
    this.userData[key] = this.$store.state.users[this.$attrs.userId][key];
  }
}
```

it just loops over the keys in the array `["userName", "salery", "leftover"]` and dynamically copy the values from the source object to `this.userData`.